# how to properly send a Post request with Axios in a firebase function?

Tags: firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions

I am having a hell of a time trying to send a post request using axios, I was wondering if anyone had some input.

```
  let grant_type: string = 'authorization_code'

await axios
    .post(
      url,
      {
        client_id: client_id,
        client_secret: client_secret,
        grant_type: grant_type,
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
        code: code,
      },
      {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www.form-urlencoded' },
      },
    )
    .then((response) => {
      functions.logger.log('---Response---')
      functions.logger.log(response)
      return response
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      functions.logger.log(error)
      return error
    })
```

The error that I am getting is

`error_description: 'The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the "grant_type" parameter.'`

If anyone can help that would be fantastic I am at a loss, I have tried the api call using postman and everything worked fine, but when I try to do it with a firebase function it doesn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: Please show the exact value of each variable, or at least of `grant_type` (since that is what the error message says is wrong).

Comment: let grant_type: string = 'authorization_code'

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved!!!!!

I had to use qs.stringify for the body params, I had saw this on some of the posts when trying to solve this my self, but it was giving me errors that stringify wasn't a function.. to fix that I change from an import statement to a require statement

below is the code!

```
const qs = require('qs')

var data = qs.stringify({
    code: code,
    client_id: client_id,
    client_secret: client_secret,
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
  })
  var config: any = {
    method: 'post',
    url: url,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    data: data,
  }

  axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      functions.logger.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      functions.logger.log(error)
    })
```